# A conjecture of Adams on the mod p cohomology of classifying spaces of Lie groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, homotopy-theory, group-cohomology

In the paper [On the mod p cohomology of BPU(p)](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2005-357-11/S0002-9947-05-03983-8/), the authors say that there is a conjecture of J. F. Adams as follows:

**Conjecture** (J. F. Adams) Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group, and let $p$ be an odd prime. Then the mod $p$ cohomology of $BG$ is detected by elementary abelian $p$-subgroups.

In other words, the homomorphism
$$H^*(BG;\mathbb{F}_p)\to \operatorname{invlim}H^*(BE;\mathbb{F}_p) $$
where the inverse limit is taken over the category of elementary abelian $p$-subgroups is injective. In particular, $E$ runs over elementary abelian $p$ subgroups of $G$.

However, I was not able to find the original document containing this conjecture. Is there one?

What is the status of this conjecture?

Comment: Is the statement supposed to mean that that homomorphism is injective? If so, the analogous question allowing $E$ to range over all finite subgroups came up not too long ago [here on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372106/is-lie-group-cohomology-determined-by-restriction-to-finite-subgroups/) (that question was for integral cohomology, but I think the second answer is general enough to cover mod $p$). The answer was yes, and I don't think it used anything unavailable to Adams. So I guess the hard part is going from finite subgroups to elementary ones?

Comment: The analogous question for $K$-theory instead of mod-$p$ cohomology, and for finite cyclic subgroups rather than elementary ones, is a theorem of McClure: see Theorem C of [Restriction maps in equivariant K-theory](https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(86)90019-4). This result was apparently the inspiration for the above MO question. I should mention that that question had previously been asked on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3821407/is-lie-group-cohomology-determined-by-restriction-to-finite-subgroups), where most of the work was actually done.

Comment: The point of using elementary abelian subgroups comes from the fact that the map is known as Quillen's map and had been studied.  Furthermore the cohomology of finite group is in general not computable, meaning that the target is not a useful approximation of the source.  And yes, the finite to elementary abelian part is far from obvious, the Quillen's map for finite groups is not in general injective.

Comment: What the Quillen map is? Is it in his paper on the Adams’ conjecture?

Comment: @user43326 Thanks for confirming that! So this is another one of those cases of "Homotopy theory reduces to finite group cohomology, but it turns out that finite group cohomology is hard!". It sounds like you're familiar with this conjecture -- do you know if it appears in print, or else have an idea of the timeframe when it was formulated?  I just noticed that in addition to McClure's Corollary C mentioned above, Corollary B of the that paper proves precisely the version of this conjecture of Adams for $K$-theory -- i.e. with $E$ ranging over elementary elementary subgroups.

Comment: @user51223 The map in the op's question...  It is actually discussed in the introduction of the paper.

Comment: @TimCampion Oh, I also should have mentioned that not only the cohomology of finite group is in general messy, but also the category of all finite subgroups of a Lie group is not easy...

Comment: @user43326 Good point. In order to prove $H^\ast(BG) \to \prod_F H^\ast(BF)$ (product over finite subgroups) is injective, one doesn't really need to consider all finite subgroups. Using the Becker-Gottlieb transfer, you end up just needing extensions of the Weyl group by finite subgroups of a maximal torus. So e.g. if you're only interested in connected $G$ (or maybe "almost-connected" $G$ like $O(n)$), the only "nonabelian part" comes from the particular Weyl groups you care about. But I think Weyl groups for classical groups have complicated cohomology anyway, so maybe that doesn't help.

Comment: @TimCampion Well, at least for symmetric groups, the Quillen's map is injective, but the cohomology of an extension of abelian groups by these isn't that easy, is it?

Comment: @user43326 I'd believe that. It's possibly relevant that you don't need to consider arbitrary extensions, but only the particular ones which show up in classical groups. But I don't know enough to say if this helps. EDIT: Hang on -- you say [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383341/a-conjecture-of-adams-on-the-mod-p-cohomology-of-classifying-spaces-of-lie-group?noredirect=1#comment975226_383341) that there are finite groups for which Quillen's map is not injective. That means Adams' conjecture is false in full generality!

Comment: I see I missed the hypothesis that $G$ be connected. For the benefit of any others who might share my confusion, note that this hypothesis (or at least _some_ hypothesis beyond compact Lie) is necessary. For example the inclusion $p \mathbb Z / p^2 \to \mathbb Z / p^2$ does not induce an injection in cohomology (it kills odd classes), even though the domain is the only nonzero elementary subgroup of the codomain. And to state explicitly: [Quillen and Venkov showed](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82251336.pdf) that the kernel of the Quillen map is nilpotent.

Comment: @TimCampion Yes, the connectedness is actually a big issue here, which is another reason why we don't want to replace a Lie group with just any finite subgroup.

Comment: It's also true for G=F_4, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.4865.pdf

Comment: I have learned a lot from this thread. One small point: In @TimCampion's first comment, I think the right theorem to refer to is McClure's Theorem D instead of Theorem C. Is that correct?

Comment: @XingGu I think McClure's Thm A, Cor B, Cor C, Thm D are all relevant. The most direct analog of Adams' conjecture would be Cor B.